# How to use extract and code splitting in Laravel Mix for React

Tags: reactjs, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

```
mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .react('resources/js/auth.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/js/core.js', 'public/js')
   .react('resources/js/workspace.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/scss/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/scss/auth.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/scss/icons.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/scss/core.scss', 'public/css')
   .extract(['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router-dom'])
```

I am using the above code, react is getting extracted but my component is not mounted, I also want to know the best way of achieving code splitting of react with laravel mix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you load manifest.js and vender.js? make sure you load them first

```
    <script src="{{mix("js/manifest.js")}}"></script>
    <script src="{{mix("js/vendor.js")}}"></script>
```

Comment: manifest.js was missing for me. Thank you.